# CSS div height 0 with child with change

Tags: css

I've this situation

```
<div class="parent">
   <p>stuff stuff stuff</p>
</div>
```

so with CSS i make the **width** and the **height** of `parent = 0;` because i want to change when a button it's click, but i need to hide the child and that have height 0, this because i want a menu like this when it's closed

> element 1 
>  element 2 
>  element 3

and when a element it's open

> element 1 
>  stuf stuf 
>  stuf stuf 
>  stuf stuf 
>    
>  element 2 
>  element 3

so the height of children have to be zero and animate, i try with display none, but it's ugli to see when you open, there a way to do it more nice

Comment: Can you share your complete code? Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What's your code so far ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

used jquery toggleClass to achieve it. thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parent").click(function() {
    $( ".parent" ).toggleClass( "height", 1000 );
  });
});
```

```css
.height {
  height: auto !important;
}

.parent {
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p>stuff stuff stuff</p>
</div>
```